# react-native-elements installation issue with react-native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I'm trying to implement searchbar using react-native-elements, but facing lots of issue, it ask me to install react-native-vector-icons, then after installing it also, again I'm getting other issues more specific to IOS(i.e., pod installation), not sure how to make it work by simply installing react-native-elements

I'm using react-native version -> "0.59.10"

I have followed this link -> https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, I deleted the node_modules folder and the ios build folder, also uninstalled the app and completely closed all command prompts, it got resolved.
Followed the steps from the above link only(i.e., https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)